# Custom ajax widget can't save generated value to database - $item always zero

Tags: database, ajax, 8

I'm currently working on a custom module that communicates with a REST API. It is implemented as a new field type with a custom widget. The entire communication with the API works fine. The thing is that I'd like to save one part of the response in the database and I can't get it to work.

My code is here:
https://github.com/stopopol/b2share/blob/master/b2share.module

Basically, I only need the information of one textfield ( $form['b2share_fieldset']['pid_button']) to be saved in the database, but the save function doesn't seem to be called.

I tried following this tutorial: http://getlevelten.com/blog/ian-whitcomb/defining-custom-field-types-drupal
but I had no success yet.
Maybe it's also important to mention that this field will be embedded in a content type together with plenty of other fields, therefore the communication with the rest api is done via ajax, but the values I get from the API should be stored together with the regular fields in the node form.

I only need someone to tell me what's missing from being able to save it. I've been stuck for days and can't figure it out.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Ok. I narrowed it down and it seems like the problem is that

`foreach ($items as $delta => $item)`

never runs because the size of $items is always 0. I haven't found the reason yet. But will post my insights here.

**EDIT2:** Thanks for the helpful comments. I used hook_submit and was able to save values in the database, but drupal is complaining about the entity_Id and delta.

Example code I found suggests a function like this:

```
 function b2share_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = array('b2share_form_submit');
   return $form;
 }

 function b2share_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 drupal_set_message( 'submit handler is called' );

 $values = array(
   'url' => $form_state['values']['b2share_fieldset']['url'],
   'pid' => $form_state['values']['b2share_fieldset']['pid']
 );

 $insert = db_insert('field_data_field_b2share')
   -> fields(array(
    'field_b2share_url' => $values['url'],
    'field_b2share_pid' => $values['pid'],
    //'entity_id' => 1,
    //'delta' => 0,
    //'language' => 'und',
))
->execute();
}
```

But apparently the functions needs to give more info or I am missing something somewhere else.

**EDIT 3:** Calling b2share_form_submit breaks the node form. The error message says: "The requested page "/.../node//current-revision" could not be found."

Logs say :

"Warning: Missing argument 3 for b2share_form_submit(),"

"Warning: Missing argument 4 for b2share_form_submit()"

**EDIT 4:** As described here in a comment ([Do something after submit the form at hook_form_alter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37719/do-something-after-submit-the-form-at-hook-form-alter)) this is the correct way to write the form_alter function:
`function b2share_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][]='b2share_form_submit';
  return $form;
}`

Comment: Attention .. you have nested functions in your code !

Comment: And what does that mean exactly? Every function in the code is called. Everything seems fine as far as I can see, except for $items.

Comment: You want to save something in hook_field_presave but are using a form, you should save your values in hook_submit.

Comment: Is it solved? If yes, please post the solution in answer.

Comment: Not quite. I can call the submission_handler and partially fill the database, but I'm not quite there yet. I will post the final solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found multiple examples on how to write your a custom submit handler, but most of them had a flaw in it. They were either always or never called. Sometimes I couldn't access the node_id, which was crucial for me.

I ended up using this:

```
function b2share_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'seal_the_deal';
}


function seal_the_deal($form, &$form_state, $entity_id, $entity_type, $form_id) {
 $values = array(
  'url' => $form_state['values']['b2share_fieldset']['url'],
  'pid' => $form_state['values']['b2share_fieldset']['pid']
 );

 if ( (empty($values['url'] == false) || (empty($values['pid']) == false)) ) {

    $insert = db_insert('field_data_field_b2share')
     -> fields(array(
        'field_b2share_url' => $values['url'],
        'field_b2share_pid' => $values['pid'],
        'entity_id' => $form_state['node']->nid,
        'entity_type' => 'node',
        'bundle' => $form_state['node']->type,
        'delta' => 0,
        'language' => 'und',
     ))
    ->execute();
     }
   }
```

Details can be found here:

[Custom submit handler is also called when deleting a node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210966/custom-submit-handler-is-also-called-when-deleting-a-node)

http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/form-altering-node-addedit-forms

[Drupal 7 custom form submit handler is not being called](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45953/drupal-7-custom-form-submit-handler-is-not-being-called)